# Exporting nodes and links from zoomcharts

Tags: zoomcharts

I'm exporting the nodes and links to a json object like this, in order to write it to disk later. This is the data as I load it:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "type": "activity",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {"label": "Testing ZoomCharts"}
    },
    {
        "id": "o1",
        "type": "organization",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {"label": "Ophileon"}
    }
],
"links": [{
    "id": "l1",
    "from": "o1",
    "to": "a1",
    "style": {"label": "Executes"}
}
}
```

When I get the nodes and links from the current graph, like this

```
    function exportNodes(){
      var nodesandlinks = {"nodes":[],"links":[]};
      nodesandlinks.nodes.push(chart._scene.data.nodes);
      nodesandlinks.links.push(chart._scene.data.links);
      alert(JSON.stringify(nodesandlinks));
    }
```

It returns a result that I need to process again in order to reload it, since it has each node as an attribute.

```
{
"nodes": [{
    "a1": {
        "id": "a1",
        "type": "activity",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {"label": "Testing ZoomCharts"}
    },
    "o1": {
        "id": "o1",
        "type": "organization",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {"label": "Ophileon"}
    }
}],
"links": [{"l1": {
    "id": "l1",
    "from": "o1",
    "to": "a1",
    "style": {"label": "Executes"}
}}]
}
```

Is there another way to retrieve the nodes?   I tried this already:

```
chart.data.nodes
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

chart.nodes
function (){return this._impl.scene.nodes()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a dedicated API function for exporting data from network chart:

```
var exportedData = chart.exportData(visibleOnly);
alert(JSON.stringify(exportedData));
```

See https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/api-reference/api/#NetChart.exportData

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
  function exportNodes(){
      var nodesandlinks = {"nodes":[],"links":[]};
      for (var n in chart._scene.data.nodes){
          nodesandlinks.nodes.push(chart._scene.data.nodes[n]);
      }
      for (var l in chart._scene.data.links){
          nodesandlinks.links.push(chart._scene.data.links[l]);
      }
      alert(JSON.stringify(nodesandlinks));
  }
```

Comment: great :)  But Is it on purpose that it has to be done this way? just exporting chart.data.nodes and chart.data.links was what I was expecting.

Comment: we will have more streamlined option in future I believe, as we plan to introduce some editing capabilities as well. accessing _scene is somewhat tricky and should not be relied on in long term :)